# Automatic refresh of a windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

In a web page, when a user click a link I open a new windows.

```
$('#visit').click(function () {
    window.open(getHostName() + "/visits" , 'VisitsReport');
});
```

In the

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var initVisit = function initVisitReport() {
        $("#visitReportTableResult").bootstrapTable({
            url: getHostName() + "/visits",
            queryParamsType: "",
            responseHandler: function (res) {
                return {
                    rows: res.content,
                    total: res.totalElements,
                    pageNumber: res.number,
                    pageSize: res.size
                };
            },
            queryParams: function (params) { //todo check if we need to put search here
                return {
                    search: params.searchText,
                    page: params.pageNumber - 1,
                    size: params.pageSize,
                    sort: params.sortName + "," + params.sortOrder
                };
            }

        });
    };
    initVisit();
}
```

I feed a [bootstrap table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table)

After the windows be open, i search a way to refresh data automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` :

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.get("url", function(result) {
    $("#visitReportTableResult").bootstrapTable({
      data: result
    });
  });
}, 10000);
```